# Quick Settings Tile in ACTIVE state on boot when ACTIVE_TILE enabled

Tags: android

When you use [META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.html#META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE), onStartListening() TileService callback, which updates Tile state will fire when you call TileService.requestListeningState().

It works, but when the device boots, Tile is in ACTIVE state until you click it. If ACTIVE_TILE not set the tile stays in INACTIVE state on boot.

How to solve it?

Android 7.1.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019996/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-quick-settings-tiles-default-state

Comment: @CodeChimp, nope, I have already use ACTIVE_TILE, but problem is in initial state on android boot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the documentation is not that clear in this case. I was having the same problem, and after several tries I found a solution for my case.

The manifest stays:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.service.quicksettings.ACTIVE_TILE"
            android:value="true" />
```

And then in the quickTileService override onBind and call RequestListeningState:

```
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
    TileService.requestListeningState(this,
            ComponentName(this, QSTileService::class.java))
    return super.onBind(intent)
}
```

And on the onStartListening you can update your tile:

```
override fun onStartListening() {
    super.onStartListening()
    updateTile()
}
```

Comment: If ACTIVE_TILE is false - QS tile will not receive requestListeningState()

Comment: Actually you are totally right. I think I figured it out. Set it to true and then use override the onBind and request a startListening where you can update your tile. I modified the answer to match this.

Hopefully this works for your case.